# Restoring deleted product alerts

Tags: catalog, products, wishlist, alert

We recently started to address requests from customers to be alerted once product comes back in stock. Basically a lot of these requests were mistakenly deleted without being addressed. Is there any way to view historical product alerts, even once they've been deleted?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, alerts are referred by product_id, once you delete the product you permanently delete your alerts.

I'm sorry, but there is no way to rebuild it in a standard way.

If you have MySQL binlog you may try to rebuild something, but it is a quite impossible way.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a backup then the answer is simple. You cannot get your alerts back.
If you have a backup you will find the alerts records in the table `product_alert_stock`.